# In which order do I have to code?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my app, the user can choose something in a spinner, and recieves a Toast with the choosen text, when he clicks a  button.

now in my case, when he clicks the button, a toast pops up, but empty. I think the shared preferences for the toast wont be actualized because they wont be recognized in the beginning of the code lines? have a look:

```
.
.
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("spinnerSelection", 0);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                spinnergipfeli.setSelection(prefs.getInt("spinnerSelection", 0));
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = (thetime);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
    });
.
.
```

and later in the code:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView myText = (TextView) view;
    editor = prefs.edit();
    selectedPosition = spinnergipfeli.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String Text = spinnergipfeli.getSelectedItem().toString();
    editor.putInt("spinnerSelection", selectedPosition);
    editor.putString("thetime", Text);
    editor.commit();
}    
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `thetime`, as in `CharSequence text = (thetime);`? I think you might want `CharSequence text = prefs.getString("thetime", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine. You just have to retrieve the "**thetime**" entry to get the String you're looking for:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        spinnergipfeli.setSelection(prefs.getInt("spinnerSelection", 0));
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String text = prefs.getString("thetime", "default empty value");
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```